Тёмный экран при переустановке windows 10
Переустанавливаю виндовс 10 с флешки (винда с оф. сайта). Сначала все было нормально: синий экран, показывающий проценты загрузки, затем предупреждение о том, что компьютер перезагрузится. Перезагрузился. И с тех пор темно-серый экран висит со вчерашнего дня. Даже не черный, монитор включается. Перезагрузка не помогла. Что делать?
Переустанавливаю не первый раз.
В биос выйти не получается. Переставлял джампер, вытаскивал батарейку с мат платы: все бесполезно.

Развёртывание  экосистемы ОС требует тщательнейшей подготовки всего и вся: дистрибутива, файловой системы, всего остального софта. И предварительного резервирования особого критичных файлов. Нажать на setup -  это далеко не всё. 30 лет этим занимаюсь. Если уже даже в биос не можете, либо наймите студента по объявлению, либо несите в ремонт. Скорее второе. С таким набором сведений Вам вряд ли помогут. Такое не делается онлайн. Я - делаю. Но даже я никогда не возьмусь делать незнакомый комп онлайн - всегда может что-то пойти не так. Так можно делать только комп, который уже подготовлен.

а хотите прикол? дело оказалось в косячно работающем удлинителе. поменял удлинитель - все заработало

@FoxFox, ваш комментарий бесполезен, он оффтопик, никого не интересует сколько лет вы этим занимаетесь, тут вопрос ответ, а комментарии для уточнения каких либо данных.
